# The document storage for app

Tags: ios, icloud, file-management

My app will download some items with its pictures from the server. Each item will be saved in the device as a document. Now, all the files are saved in the app`s "Document" file.

I forget from which documentation I have read that the files stored in the "Document" file will be applied for iCloud storage. So if I did not need the iCloud service, is it necessary for me to put these files in the Caches file or other files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing called app's "Document" file. I predict perhaps you meant the `Documents` folder. `Documents` folder exists both on the device's local sandbox and on the iCloud.

Based on the user preference your app may need to move documents between local sandbox and iCloud relative to `Documents` sub-folder.

You need to follow Apple guidelines for Document-based Applications in IOS [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).